# How do I edit the text and images of a carousel post on a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When creating a carousel post for my page on Facebook, I can enter some text underneath each image added to the carousel.

However, I can't find a way to edit this text after posting it. When I choose `Edit Post` from the menu of the post, it only allows editing the main text of the post, above the carousel, but does not allow editing the carousel itself (the photo or the text under each photo).

Answer (score 0):

**Facebook posts which have been boosted, or are part of an ad campaign, cannot be edited.**

In order to edit them you need to go to the Ads Manager and deactivate the carousel

You can edit the different parts of your carousel one by one:

- To edit each of the destinations URLs, hover over each image and click the link icon.
- To edit the text below the image, click on the text and edit it.
- To edit the headline, just click on it and edit it's text.

Comment: That answer does not match my question. My post is not boosted and I am able to enter edit mode. However edit mode doesn't allow editing the carousel, only the post main content.